# How to consume a specific maximum number of messages from a Kafka Topic?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I wish to consume a specific number of maximum messages per consume from a kafka topic. I have used the following code:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers=[server], max_poll_records=2, api_version=(0, 10))

for message in consumer:
    string = message.value.decode("utf-8")
    dict_value = ast.literal_eval(string)
```

But by doing this I am not able to restrict the maximum messages per consume to two.

Answer (score 1):

This *waits* to poll two records **each fetch request**,and will **continue** indefinitely until the application is killed.

As answered before, collect events to a list + break the loop after you get only two messages.

Or use something like this

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(...)
m1 = next(consumer)
m2 = next(consumer)
```

Or modify the producer code to produce two events together so that the consumer reads them as "one" record